# SQL: Two databases, both has table with column of common values. How to find missing rows

Tags: sql

I have two databases, both databases has a table with a column of common values. What I am trying to achieve is to get all records, where database1 table1(with common values) record do not have counterpart in database2 table2(with common values).
Which is the best method to get these records? Is there any resource light way to do that, where database performance is not affected?

For example:

```
Database1
Table1 - id/number(common value)/object/name

Database2
Table1 - table_id/number(common value)/table_object/table_name
```

lets say that database1 table1 column "number" has values: 1,2,3 and database2 table1 column "number" has values 1,2,3,4,5
Now I need to find these two records, what are missing in database1, but what are excisting in database2( in this example, I am looking records where "number" value in database2 are 4 and 5)

Comment: try this ... `select * from db1.table1 where id not in (select id from db2.table2);`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL is just a _query language_ not a DBMS product.

Comment: There are tools for this: buy, don't build e.g. [Redgate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

Comment: In SQL Server I'd use [`EXCEPT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188055.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To access objects (tables, procedures) of different database, you need to setup a mechanism by which you can access the object of different database.

You can look into these resources for that 
[Cross Database Access in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669059(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff772782.aspx).

Once you're able to access both the databases in a query, then your query would be pretty straight forward like this

```
SELECT database2.table1.number FROM database2.table1 
WHERE database2.table1.number NOT EXISTS (SELECT database1.table1.number FROM database1.table1)
```

Comment: This fails to handle NULLs properly. If you have a NULL in database1.table1, this query will return 0 records. Use NOT EXISTS with a correlated subquery or handle NULLs properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can reach these missing records from three ways: 
* Note That it will help you if you want to find missing values in database2 comparing with database1, and if Id of tables are common too ,it is better to join on id instead of number.

```
select * 
from database2.dbo.table1 As D2 
left join database1.dbo.table1 As D1 on D1.number = D2.number
where D1.Number is null


select * 
from database2.dbo.table1  
where number not in (
select number  from database1.dbo.table1 ) 

select * 
from database2.dbo.table1 As  D2
where number  NOT EXISTS  (
select number  from database1.dbo.table1 As D1 where D1.number = D2.number   )
```

Comment: Your NOT IN query has the same problem as Sachin's one. It will return zero records if there is a record with number = NULL in database1. Either add a where condition, or be sure, that number is not nullable.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! Some additional questions arose. Above queries seems to work fluently if databases are on the same server.
But not so fluently if databases are on different servers, which are linked. There were also collation issue and I had to use collate clause, does it affects performance?
Is there any other resource light way to compare these tables?

Comment: thats right, I assume number is not nullable but if we had null in number we can write query like this : 
' select * 
from database2.dbo.table1  
where number is not null and number not in (
select number  from database1.dbo.table1  where number is not null ) '

Comment: so using Collation will effect on your performance , but if your data is not too much , maybe it doesn't  effect so ,but if you see it make your query slowly you can use the solutions for that , I read  some same question like this on stackoverflow for that .